# Water in my back tire

Tags: tire

I commute 17 miles to and from work each day on a road bike, and I recently picked up a puncture. This was no problem. However, on my ride to work this morning it was raining rather heavily and there was a lot of standing water on the road. I have somehow managed to get water into my rear tire. I was wondering if this is normal and should I deflate the tire and let the water out?

Should I also get a new back tire? I can’t see any holes in it and the inner tube only had the smallest of holes in it.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! I've cleaned up your question, but please roll back my edit if I've indadvertedly change the meaning of your text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you mean water is in the tire - between tire and tube - or in the tube?  The only way for water to get in the tube would be via the valve (or, very rarely, if you rode the punctured tire flat for an extended period).

Water between tire and tube is no big deal -- should work its way out quickly.

Inside the tube should probably be drained (requiring removing tube from tire) and would be most likely due to water in your pump (or a compressor used to fill the tire).  Cycle the pump a few strokes before putting it on the valve, if you've ridden in the rain recently, and make sure any compressor you use is drained regularly.

Comment: Between tier and tube. It's a great relief to hear its nothing to worry about, thank you for your help

Comment: Water may have not been inside the tire, but inside the rim. A rim that is not designed to be part of a tubeless system is by no means hermetic. Water can enter ir by the holes for the poke heads and the hole for the valve. A double wall rim would have a nice cavity that can be easily filled with water while riding ponds. Then while you dissasembled the wheel, water went down to the space between tire and tube. Again Nothing to worry about.